# Postgres allows duplicate foreign keys one with cascade delete one without. Does that makes sense?

Tags: postgresql, foreign-keys

I am working on an existing Postgres 13.x DB I noticed these two FK in an ER Diagram.  Does it make sense to have both of these?  They seem to contradict each other.  Just one of these FK would make sense to me and not both.  Any harm in having both?  I am surprised Postgres allows both.

```
ALTER TABLE table_x ADD CONSTRAINT fk_x_1
FOREIGN KEY (field_x) REFERENCES table_x(unid);
ALTER TABLE table_x ADD CONSTRAINT fk_x_2
FOREIGN KEY (field_x) REFERENCES table_x(unid) ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

Comment: That is going to error out on the second FK as you cannot have duplicate constraint names on a given table. You could change the name and get the second FK, but as you say that does not make sense.

Comment: Thanks I updated the FK constraint names and I agree I am surprised Postgres allows this situation.

Comment: Why would the database reject something like this? You can't change the behavior of an existing foreign key without creating a new foreign key. It makes sense to drop the old foreign key, but that's up to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create both foreign key constraints, but it doesn't make any sense. Either you want deletes to cascade to the referencing table or not.

Still, it makes sense to allow both constraints: imagine you have a foreign key constraint without cascading delete, and you want to convert it to cascading delete. Since there is no `ALTER CONSTRAINT`, you'd have to create the new constraint, then drop the old one, to ensure that the foreign key relationship can never be violated.

Comment: But when you have both it is confusing which one is chosen.  I am reading a post you also did on figuring out the order (looks to be the first one added).
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77264492/check-foreign-key-constraint-order-in-postgresql

Comment: No, that's what the SQL standard decrees. PostgreSQL does it in alphabetical order, like [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/trigger-definition.html) details.